# Django Rest Framework's IsAuthenticated() method is failing for AnonymousUser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a ListView and it has permission set to IsAuthenticated, when I hit the URL in an incognito window, I'm able to view the data without having the user logged in.

Here is my serializer

```
class BlogListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
    view_name="blog_api:post_detail",
    lookup_field="slug"
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = [
           'url',
           'title',
           'category',
           'date',
           'publish',
           'draft'
         ]
```

Below is my view

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class BlogListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter(publish=True, draft=False)
    serializer_class = BlogListSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Settings files

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Middleware settings

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

So what's happening is, when I try to access the user by calling get_object on BlogListAPIView, it throws an error  is not JSON serializable. For some reason, middleware is taking AnonymousUser as a User. If there is AnonymousUser logged in it should fail IsAuthenticated permission. This is what basically should happen
Why AnonymousUser is getting accessed and IsAuthenticated() failing?

Comment: Please, make sure you question is clear. You state that "it works perfectly" so what the actual issue ?

Comment: have you defined DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES  & DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES in settings.py? can you put those values here ?

Comment: @Linovia It works perfectly fine for IsAdmin Permission.

Comment: @SajiXavier Yes I've declared DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES & DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES

Comment: my bad, I didn't spotted the difference in the permission names. As @SajiXavier said, please provide your settings's DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES. It feels like there are none.

Comment: @Linovia does it have to do something with AnonymousUser. As I tried to access the user by calling get method, it said AnonymousUser is not JSON serializable
    <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x04135530> 
     is not JSON serializable

Comment: What do you mean by "`get_method` on `BlogListAPIView`"? `AnonymousUser` means no user is logged in. Why are you serializing it? Do you get 200 when hitting the page without user or get an error?

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani I meant get_object, so I used the get_object method to print logged in user. I'm not serializing it, DRF CBV serializes the output by default. I get 200 without a user, it bypasses IsAuthenticated permission when no user is logged in.

Comment: @NikhilShirsath `get_object` is not related to logged in user. Could you provide the code you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was gone by upgrading from Django 1.9 to Django 1.10  and using DRF 3.3.7.

Answer (score 5):

There is certainly some other problems that is not listed in your question. I created a fresh project with snippets you provided and will get http 401 when I hit the URL without logging in. I provided codes in Github:

get https://github.com/Rmaan/pastebin/tree/so-47596482

runserver and browse to http://localhost:8000/blog

Comment: Can you test using dj 1.9, i have the same problem in this version?

Comment: I guess it is related to some middleware issue. @Arman's post is not an answer. With a fresh project, the issue will go away. But certainly, I'm at such stage of the project where I can't afford to fresh start the project.

Comment: @NikhilShirsath I have another project with the same problem, that's why i offered the bounty

Comment: @NikhilShirsath I know that it won't help you but it's the answer to your question. I just showed things you provided in the question won't produce the problem you claim. I didn't mean "do a fresh start and problem will go away!" you should provide more detail about authentication and you code.

Comment: @AssemChelli What's your DRF version? I doubt there is a problem with older versions of Django/DRF, authentication is a basic part of DRF but I'll test.

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani What other details on authentication apart from Serializer class, view and my settings snippets that I've already shared you'd like me to share?

Comment: @NikhilShirsath Maybe middlewares. Any decorators on your views. Any custom authentication backend.

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani I've updated the post. There aren't any decorators on the view.